# Swagger v3 - Selecting multiple values from given set of values

Tags: swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have a parameter that a list of Strings, but the values must belong from a set of values.

This is what I have tried

```java
@Parameter(description = "The type of status filters", content = @Content(array = @ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(implementation = String.class, allowableValues = {"Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"}))))
```

What I'm currently getting
[image: current output]

As you can see, there is a text field.

I would like to have a drop-down instead.

Any suggestions on how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by removing the `implementation` part

```java
@Parameter(description = "The type of status filters", content = @Content(array = @ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(allowableValues = {"Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"}))))
```